# How to overwrite 0 sector under Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, mbr, bootsector

Is there any built in Windows XP command or other utility which will let me overwrite sector 0, so the OS will be non-bootable?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Specifically, what is your goal here?

Comment: In my hardware configuration I need to make HDD non-bootable in order to boot PC from LAN(PXE). If BIOS detects bootable OS, then PXE is not engaged.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a tool, from within Windows XP, that will make overwrite the 0 sector, on the same drive that Windows XP is running on?  If that is your question, the answer to that question, is **no**  Please clarify your question, and perhaps describe the problem you are trying to solve, so the best solution can be provided.

Comment: Dell had a dos utility called Clean1K, you would boot from a dos environment and run it, it would overwrite the first 1k of the hard drive. I still have a copy of it. These days I use Dban to get that job done.

Comment: @Ramhound: the answer is yes. It is possible to overwrite 0 sector on running Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with MBRWizard. It has nice option called Wipe.

Comment: You did not specify it could be a third party utility. Your question was misleading.

Comment: `Other Utility` next to Windows XP command implies to third party utility.

Comment: disagree, subject to interpretation, it is not clear when used in same sentence and not specify 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

[Diskpart is built into Windows XP](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/diskpart.mspx?mfr=true), there is a clean command in Diskpart that erases the first 1k.

[clean will remove the partition or volume formatting from the current disk](https://neosmart.net/wiki/diskpart/#Commands_and_parameters)

Comment: This doesn't solve my question. I need to delete the active(and the only) hard drive.